# How to see which workstation on our network went to a certain site

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, routing, logging

We had someone order a laptop from Staples.com with one of our company credit cards on Sept 25.  It showed up at our office on the 27th, nobody knew who ordered it, and then it was gone... Someone ordered and stole it.

Is there anyway I can see who visited staples.com on Sept 25, based on DNS or traffic logs of any kind?

We are a fairly small company.  We have a single active directory server which handles DHCP and DNS (Windows 2008 R2).

We have a Safe@Office 500P router.

I could also UNC to all individual workstations, if there is any sort of local DNS log on the machine itself.

Based on my preliminary checks, it looks like we're not logging anything that can help me track this down.  I was hoping someone could suggest something to prove me wrong, though :).

Thanks!

EDIT: Just some additional information I forgot to mention: we have talked to Staples.com and we got the IP Address.  It was ordered from our office.

Also, the Safe@Office 500P router does seem to do some logging, but it only seems to keep today's logs (strange right?).  We have setup a Syslog Server for it to send logs to, but it was done after-the-fact.

We found out the email address of the person who ordered it and it is a GMail.com address.  When I put that in to a Contacts List in Gmail, it will show me the first and last name which is "Rob Lowe".  There is no Rob Lowe working here.

Comment: Rob Lowe is an actor from the West Wing and Parks and Rec. I doubt he stole a laptop from you :)

Comment: @MDMarra - saying that Rob Lowe is an actor is stretching things a bit... Bryan Cranston, that's an actor.

Comment: Are you serious? Sam Seaborn was the best character on West Wing until he left! Seaborn for president!

Comment: (Off Topic - Apologies) I have to admit that I like Rob Lowe on Parks and Recreation. I had to watch it last night to get over the gut punch from Breaking Bad last Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not proactively logging this, there's likely nothing useful short of going to every PC and looking at the browsing history and hoping they haven't already erased it.

How do you know they did it from on your network anyway? Chances are they would do something like this from an off-site computer anyway.

Comment: Thanks MDMarra, we have talked to some folks at Staples.com and they gave us the IP Address of the person who ordered it.  It is definitely our office IP.  It was ordered by a gmail.com address.  If you put the address into the Gmail.com Contacts list, it will show the first and last name of the person.  The first/last name is "Row Lowe".

Comment: I'm assuming DNS logging on the server was never turned on?  Info on how to turn it on/check current settings here: https://support.appriver.com/KB/a669/enable-dns-request-logging-for-windows-20032008.aspx

Comment: Shoot, you are correct.  That is not enabled...  Is it likely that an ISP would log DNS?  I may check with them...

Comment: It's a long shot, but you could also ask Staples if they can provide a user agent from their web logs -- this might narrow it down if your machines aren't totally homogenous and your router doesn't proxy this info.

Comment: The ISP would likely only have the source IP as your public IP -- your local DNS server is likely the one that fielded the request from the offender's system.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I'll have my coworker who is in contact with Staples ask that question.  Immediately after posting my last comment, I realized the ISP DNS Log wouldn't help because it would be our external IP. Argh